# just PHP not working on Wamp-Server installation on Win7 64bit

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, wampserver

When installing (and re-installing) Wampserver 2.5 I ran into this problem today:

Everyting set up fine and running "green" in wampServer, without any reported errors in PHP-/Apache-/mySQL

works (without any php-lines):

```
http://localhost/someHTMLfile.html
```

doesn't work (even withoput php-code inside):

```
http://localhost/someHTMLfile.php
```

The Problem: passing through files that would be processed by/to the php-parser/module result in a blank browser screen / "website not reachable"

Comment: where did you put your file..is that wamp/www/somefile.php?

Comment: @MuhammadAli The files have been in the same "physical" directory. As stated above, local setup did work fine, just not with php. See the solution below... :)

Answer (score 1):

As a 64bit Windows7 user you have to do some correction in the 2.5 wampServer config.
Although the server is "green", online and nothing is reported as malfunctioning,
the parsing stalls if the php module is fed.

As seen on http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123685 there is an incomplete parameter in the my.ini file.
This file is reachable and editable by the wampserverManager TrayIcon -> mySQL - > my.ini

You may want to change the line

```
[wampmysqld]
```

into

```
[wampmysqld64]
```

to get everything working just as it should.

Maybe it's just me stepping in some RTM-Trap.
Maybe it's not just me, though.